# mybatis does not run neo4j cypher script properly?

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, mybatis

I am trying out neo4j-jdbc with mybatis with the following cypher script:

```
MATCH (p:CouponProgram)-[r]->(s:Solution) RETURN labels(p)[0] as src, id(p) as srcId, p.name as srcName, p.code as srcCode, p.discount as srcDiscount, type(r) as relation, labels(s)[0] as tgt, id(s) as tgtId, s.description as tgtDescription
```

the script runs all right with neo4j's web ui:
[image]

However, when the same script is carried out by mybatis, I got "java.lang.StackOverflowError" error:

```
2017-10-18 07:16:39.579 DEBUG 37849 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.e.n.mapper.Neo4jMapper.getAll4Test02   : ==>  Preparing: MATCH (p:CouponProgram)-[r]->(s:Solution) RETURN labels(p)[0] as src, id(p) as srcId, p.name as srcName, p.code as srcCode, p.discount as srcDiscount, type(r) as relation, labels(s)[0] as tgt, id(s) as tgtId, s.description as tgtDescription 
2017-10-18 07:16:39.587 DEBUG 37849 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.e.n.mapper.Neo4jMapper.getAll4Test02   : ==> Parameters: 
2017-10-18 07:16:39.634 DEBUG 37849 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.e.n.mapper.Neo4jMapper.getAll4Test02   : <==      Total: 10
2017-10-18 07:16:46.787 ERROR 37849 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:293) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.http.driver.CypherExecutor.getServerVersion(CypherExecutor.java:254) ~[neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.http.HttpDatabaseMetaData.<init>(HttpDatabaseMetaData.java:38) ~[neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.http.HttpDatabaseMetaData.<init>(HttpDatabaseMetaData.java:43) ~[neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.http.HttpConnection.getMetaData(HttpConnection.java:105) ~[neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.http.HttpConnection.getMetaData(HttpConnection.java:40) ~[neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getNextResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:254) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getNextResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:259) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getNextResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:259) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getNextResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:259) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
```

[image]

When I check the result set after the script is executed by mybatis, I found the result set is null?!
[image]

Please advise.

Comment: Please, don't use print screen of error messages. Instead, copy and paste the error message. This way the text content will be indexed and other users dealing with the same issue will found your question more easily.

Comment: @BrunoPeres thanks for the heads-up, the stack trace in plain text is added

Comment: do tou have the same error if you are using the bolt jdbc connector instead of the http one ?

Comment: please specify neo4j version and neo4j-jdbc version.
If neo4j 3.x+ I suggest you to use the new bolt protocol that is better and will be more updated